# How to include a select input in edit view in voyager project?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

My problem is the next in a voyager project I'm working on. I have an `enterprise` table and a `users` table.

I need to add a select input in the edit view of `users` table - but this view is in `vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\users\edit-add.blade.php`

I tried to add the select like:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="enterprise">Enterprises</label>
              <select name="enterprise_id" id="inputEnterprise_id" class="form-control">
                  @foreach ($enterprises as $enterprise)
                        <option value="{{$enterprise['id']}}">{{$enterprise['name']}}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>
</div>
```

I wrote the controller so it gets the data from the table. But, when I go to voyager and I try to edit some user, I have an exception error where says that the `$enterprises` var is not defined.

My `edit()` function in controller:

```
public function edit()
{
    $enterprises = Enterprise::all();
    return view('users.edit-add',compact('enterprises'));
}
```

Can someone tell me what the bug is?

Comment: post your controller `edit()` function.

Comment: `public function edit()
    {
        $enterprises = Enterprise::all();
        return view('users.edit-add',compact('enterprises'));

    }`

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Undefined variable: enterprises (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/voyager/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/users/edit-add.blade.php)

Comment: The stack not just the error. You may want to update your question with this info.

Comment: This is the only that appear in console:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Check the `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Ok, do you want that I paste all the log here?, is too big.
Edit: sorry, im new in stackoverflow.